# Restrict multiple login for a user in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am attempting to restrict multiple login from a single user in my webapp and for the same I am following this tutorial:

https://dev.to/fleepgeek/prevent-multiple-sessions-for-a-user-in-your-django-application-13oo

I followed this step by step and when I am logging in using postman(or anything):

```
http://localhost:8000/api/token/
```

I am unable to see any session that has been created in the ORM. Is it because I am using `JWTAuthentication` ?

apps.py

```
class AccountsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'users'
    
    def ready(self):
        import users.signals
```

signals.py

```
@receiver(user_logged_in)
def on_user_logged_in(sender, request, **kwargs):
    LoggedInUser.objects.get_or_create(user=kwargs.get('user'))


@receiver(user_logged_out)
def on_user_logged_out(sender, **kwargs):
    LoggedInUser.objects.filter(user=kwargs.get('user')).delete()
```

Models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_company = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_employee = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_client = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    @property
    def full_name(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name



class LoggedInUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='logged_in_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # Session keys are 32 characters long
    session_key = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

When I try `runserver` with this configuration it shows the following error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't
> unique, duplicates: users

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'corsheaders',
    'users',
    'users.apps.AccountsConfig',
```

Where `users` is the application name

Comment: It's `accounts.apps.AccountsConfig`, not  `users.apps.AccountsConfig` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: Also note that this tutorial only works for `SessionAuthentication`.

Comment: @EnePaul But my app name is `users` not `accounts` thus it should be `users.apps.AccountsConfig`

Comment: Then remove `'users'` from your `INSTALLED_APPS`